# Change source and destination adresses from a valid captured ping to create a valid ping with different source and destination

Tags: ping, icmp, traffic

I want to create traffic in my network, especially
I want to send a repetitive ping to the device with the IP 192.168.3.146 from my traffic generator (IP 192.168.3.100) (see scematic)

For the creation of the ping I captured a ping from PC to device with the IP 192.168.3.145 and modified this, meaning I changed

- the source IP
- the destination IP
- the source MAC
- and the destination MAC

I now also calclulate a new IP header checksum.

[image: Topology]

If everything is done correctly the sent ping from 192.168.100 to 192.168.3.146 should be answered I assume. Still it does not happen.

For troubleshooting I only changed the destination IP and destination MAC of the captured ping and sent it with my traffic generator. Meaning from my traffic generator I sent pings from with source IP 192.168.3.1 and destination IP 192.168.3.146 (+calculation the new IP header checksum). However, this pings are answered by the device.

I use TAP in order to capture the traffic.
I hope this is clearly described.

Thanks for answering.

Comment: Did you recalculate the checksum?

Comment: No. Can you explain me how to do it?

Comment: See this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65101552/how-do-i-calculate-the-fcs-field-in-an-ethernet-frame)

Answer (score 0):

You need to recalculate both the frame's FCS (possibly automatic, depending on tool) and the IPv4 header's checksum.

Since the spoofed host's stack isn't waiting for an ICMP Echo Reply, you'd need to detect the reply using packet capturing, either on the spoofed host, a monitoring switch port or similar.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me partly. I am still having some problems I modyfied the question accordingly.

Comment: Are you sure the FCS is recalculated as well? If not, the frame gets dropped by any L2 node (switch, NIC, ...).